# padding-left text only on menu bar

Tags: html, css, menu, padding

I've been trying to indent (further right) 'exhibition', but whenever I change the cell padding it simultaneously changes the spacing between the child elements. The other problem is that I want to make sure the bar that appears via hover remains the full width of the screen. Any thoughts?

http://jsfiddle.net/zuVu7/61/

HTML

```
<body class="bg">

<div>
<nav>
     <ul id="mainmenu">

          <li id="liServices" class="active"><a href="#" class="maintextcolour">EXHIBITIONS</a>
             <ul id="SubMenuY2" class="submenu">
                 <li><a href="current.html" class="subtextcolour">CURRENT</a></li>
                 <li><a href="previous2.html" class="subtextcolour">PREVIOUS</a></li>     
             </ul></li>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
    @charset "UTF-8";
    /* CSS Document */

    .bg {
        background-attachment:fixed; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        -moz-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    background-color:#666;
        margin: 0;
        }

    #mainmenu {
      margin: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      position: relative;  
      padding-left:0;
      top:100px; 
    }


    #mainmenu li {
      clear: left;
       position:relative;
    }


    #mainmenu a {
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      float: left;
     width:100%;
      position:relative;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        padding-left:30px;
        line-height: 42px;
  }

    #mainmenu > li:hover > a {
      background-position: 0 0;
      background-color:clear;
      background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
       width:100%;
       \
     opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: none;
  }

    #mainmenu li.active a {
      background-position: 0 0;
      background-color:clear;
        width:100%; 
    }

    .submenu {
      list-style-type: none; 
      float: left;
      display: none;
      position:absolute;
      left: 80px;
      top:0px;
      width: auto;
    }

    #mainmenu li a:hover + .submenu, .submenu:hover {
      display:block;
    } 

    .submenu li {
      display: inline-block; 
      clear: none !important;
    }

    .submenu li a {
      float: right;
      margin-left: 10px;  
    }


    .maintextcolour {
        font-family: LetterGothic, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding-top:11px;
        cursor: url(cart3.png), auto;   
    }

    .subtextcolour {
        font-family: LetterGothic, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-top:11px;
        cursor: url(cart3.png), auto;
    }

    .subtextcolour:hover {
        font-family: LetterGothic, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#666;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-top:11px;
        cursor: url(cart3.png), auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right here in your css:

```
#mainmenu {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;  
  padding-left:0;
  top:100px;

}
```

I was able to change it to:

```
#mainmenu {
  **margin-left: 150px;**
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;  
  padding-left:0;
  top:100px;

}
```

Which moved the exhibitions over to the right about 150px without changing the child elements.  The part surrounded by *'s is the only part I changed.

**Edit:

Well, the only other thing I can think of would be to add a non-breaking space: `&nbsp`;

That would make it look like this:

```
<body class="bg">


<div>
<nav>
     <ul id="mainmenu">

<li class="active"><a href="#" class="maintextcolour">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EXHIBITIONS </a>
             <ul id="SubMenuY2" class="submenu">
                 <li><a href="current.html" class="subtextcolour">CURRENT</a></li>
                 <li><a href="previous2.html" class="subtextcolour">PREVIOUS</a></li>     
             </ul></li>
    </nav>
    </div>
<img src="line.jpg" align="top" width="100%" height="1" />
</div>

<br />
```

CSS:

```
    @charset "UTF-8";
    /* CSS Document */

    .bg {
        background-attachment:fixed; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        -moz-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    background-color:#666;
        margin: 0;
        }

    #mainmenu {
      margin: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      position: relative;  
      padding-left:0;
      top:100px;

    }


    #mainmenu li {
      clear: left;
       position:relative;
    }


    #mainmenu a {
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      float: left;
     width:100%;
      position:relative;
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        padding-left:30px;
        line-height: 42px;



    }

    #mainmenu > li:hover > a {
      background-position: 0 0;
      background-color:clear;
      background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
       width:100%;
       \
     opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transition: none;


    }

    #mainmenu li.active a {
      background-position: 0 0;
      background-color:clear;
        width:100%; 


    }

    .submenu {
      list-style-type: none; 
      float: left;
      display: none;
      position:relative; 
          left: 120px;
          top: -53px;
      width: auto;
    }

    #mainmenu li a:hover + .submenu, .submenu:hover {
      display:block;
    } 

    .submenu li {
      display: inline-block; 
      clear: none !important;

    }

    .submenu li a {
      float: right;

    }


    .maintextcolour {
        font-family: LetterGothic, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding-top:11px;
        cursor: url(cart3.png), auto;


    }





    .subtextcolour {
        font-family: LetterGothic, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    font-size: 14px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top:11px;
    cursor: url(cart3.png), auto;
}

.subtextcolour:hover {
    font-family: LetterGothic, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#666;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top:11px;
    cursor: url(cart3.png), auto;
}
```

It's not very pretty on the HTML, but it works.  Then you just have to change the left positioning of the submenu for however much you move the mainmenu over.

Comment: But this results in the grey coloured band that appears via hover to no longer be the full width of the screen, right? I'm trying to indent the text without changing the position of the band (margin = 0)...if that makes sense.

Comment: This might be the reason it's so hard to do this: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Comment: Yes, I thought of adding &nbsp; and it does work, but I was hoping there was a less messy css for it. Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out: text-indent:150px; on .maintextcolour I had tried padding-left on that class but it didn't have any effect. this works.